# How to decide whether a language is decidable when not involving turing machines?

Tags: undecidability

For instance, consider L = {k : the binary expansion of sqrt(2) contains k consecutive 1s}. Obviously Rice Theorem would not work. I also tried the method of how it is to PCP undecidable but still no luck. How to prove that this is undecidable?

Comment: Why would this be undecidable? You **can** calculate the binary expansion

Comment: Your language is decidable.

Comment: What do you mean by "the binary expansion of 2"?

Comment: I missed a sqrt, sorry. It's updated now.

Comment: This language (even after the edit) can be decided in constant time, so no method should work.

Comment: I don't brlieve this is decidable since there is infinite amount of digits in the binary expansion of a float.

Comment: @gauchopig It might come as a surprise to you, but the language $L=\{k\in\mathbb N : \text{the binary expansion of }\sqrt 2\text{ contains }k\text{ consecutive } 1\text{s}\}$ is decidable, even if we have NO idea how to construct an algorithm that can determine whether the binary expansion of $\sqrt 2$ contains $k$ consecutive $1$s or not given arbitrary $k$.

Comment: (On the other hand, some people have claimed proving $\sqrt 2$ is normal in base 2, which implies $L=\mathbb N$, which is trivially decidable.)

Comment: Hint: one can decide this problem with a truly simple finite state automaton that does nothing resembling the calculation of the digits of $\sqrt{2}$. The problem has a major degeneracy that you can exploit.

Comment: @Yonatan N Thank you for the hint. Do you mean the language is equivalent to N so a DFA that accepts N is enough?

Comment: It might be, but I have no proof that it is (claimed proofs of the fact are not currently generally accepted afaik). But, if it is not equal to $\mathbb{N}$, then that means that there is some minimal $k'$ that is not in the language. Supposing you knew this $k'$, could you write a program to decide your problem? Phrased alternatively, is the language decidable regardless of the value of $k'$?

Comment: Are you suggesting that this is a countably infinite set of numbers (i.e. the program should accept all natural numbers greater than k')?

Comment: Could you share more insights please? I still want to know why this is decidable.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Have you considered accepting my answer? Please comment if my answer can be improved. (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 4):

It might come as a surprise to you, but the language $$L=\{k\in\mathbb N :\text{the binary expansion of} \sqrt2\text{ contains $k$ consecutive $1$s}\}$$ is decidable, even if we could not *construct* an *algorithm* that can demonstrate whether the binary expansion of $\sqrt2$ contains $k$ consecutive $1$s or not given arbitrary $k$.

As Yonatan N indicated, let us take a closer look at $L$. There are two disjoint cases.

- $L$ is $\mathbb N$. Then $L$ is trivially decidable. For any given $k$, just return "Yes".
- $L$ is not $\mathbb N$. Then there are some numbers in $\mathbb N$ that is not in $L$. Let $m$ be the minimum of such number. Then $L$ must be $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, m-1\}$. Why?

  - Since $m>2$ is the minimum number that is not in $L$, $m-1$, which is a number smaller than $m$, must be in $L$. That is, $\text{bin}(\sqrt 2)$ contains $m-1$ consecutive $1$s. So it also contain $k$ consecutive $1$s for all $k\le m-1$.
  - Since $\text{bin}(\sqrt 2)$ does not contains $m$ consecutive $1$s, it does not contain $k$ consecutive $1$s for any $k\gt m$. That is, $k\not\in L$.

  Now we can construct an algorithm that decides $L$. For any given $k$, check whether $k\lt m$. If yes, return "Yes". Otherwise, return "No".

In either case, there *exists* an algorithm that decides $L$. Hence $L$ is decidable.

---

Most people, I believe, felt a bit disoriented the first time when this kind of proof/conclusion was encountered. Or at least myself.

The essential point is we do not have to identify/construct/bind to one algorithm that decides $L$.  We do not have to understand fully what is $L$. All we need is there *exists* an algorithm that decides $L$, whatever $L$ turns out to be. This deviates from "the naive sense of decidability" that you might have even before you encountered the theory of computation/decidability/computability.

In particular, I do not know whether $L$ is $\mathbb N$ or not. Some people claimed to have proved that $L=\mathbb N$. I have not checked their proof, yet. Although it is certainly interesting to find whether $L=\mathbb N$, its result will not change the fact that $L$ is decidable.